# Countif date includes year, month or day

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I have a column containing dates in a Google sheet. How can I count the number of dates that include a specific year, month or day?

I have tried the following: `=COUNTIF(G:G, YEAR(2000))` which just returns a zero, although there are multiple dates in the year 2000 in that column.

All the best!

Answer (score 9):

year:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(YEAR(G:G), 2000))
```

[image: 0]

month:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(MONTH(G:G), 11))

=INDEX(COUNTIFS(MONTH(G:G), 12, G:G, "<>"))
```

day:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(DAY(G:G), 27))
```

weekday:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(WEEKDAY(G:G, 1), 7))
```